# Spans, Vector spaces problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Consider the relation between the following vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, $a=(-3,1,2)$, $b=(-1,2,5)$ and $c=(1,3,8)$ given by $(-7,-1,-4)=3a-2b$
>
> 1. Find another way to write $(-7,-1,-4)$ as a linear combination of the vectors $\{a,b,c\}$
> 2. *Using your previous answer*, check if the set $\{a,b,c\}$ is linearly dependent or not

I have reached the point of getting the RREF of the augmented matrix, I could also determine basic and free variables, I reached the point to have this:

\begin{align}X_1 &= 3 + X_3\\X_2 &= -2 -2X_3\end{align}

I could not determine what is the next step to prove or to reach another way of writing a linear combination $(-7,-1,-4)$ of $a,b,c$.

Comment: See after u have done the first part, the next part becomes easy. Use the fact  that in a three dimensional space a set of three linearly independent vectors always form a basis in which case any other vector in that space can be written uniquely as the linear combination of the basis vectors. In your case if you do part a you can see you have written the same vector in two different linear combination.

Comment: Ok perfect, however, I couldn't proceed after reaching this form: X1 = 3+ X3 , X2 = -2 -2X3, I even do not know if this is the required answer?

Comment: How about 2a-c. Check that!

Comment: As a matter of fact that you can actually get the linear dependence relation among the three vectors now after you have found the two different linear combinations.

Comment: Ok now I have 2 different linear equations but I'm not able to see how to transform them into linear combinations, I always stop at this point, I think the way is to write them as a vector and then factor out the free variable? if not could you please clarify what is the next step?

Comment: Write $x_3$ =k  then you have $x_1$=3+2k and $x_2$=-2-2k . So the solution for $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$=(3,-2,0)+k(1,-2,1). Now you can put any value of k. If you put k=-1 you get 2a-c=0

Comment: Now I understand this so clearly, thank you so much. For question b) is it linearly independent or not?

Comment: is a,b,c linearly independent or not, how could i determine this?

Answer (score 0):

Just as I said in my first comment that if a,b,c were linearly independent then it will form a basis in which case every element of the space can be written  uniquely as a linear combination of a,b,c. But from part a you can clearly see (-7,-4,-1) has been written in more that one way as a linear combination of a,b,c which says that it is not a basis.
Explicitly if you want to see a linear  dependence relation among a,b,c just equate the two linear combination that is we have 3a+2b=2a-c which says a+2b+c=0.